JerseyTest - readEntity with generic type
I have a generic class that is used as a response by all resources in my API
public class TestResponse<T> {
    private boolean result;
    private int status;
    private T data;
    // Getters and Setters
}

I have two more classes that are used to instantiate the TestResponse.Data field from two different resources
public class TestResponseData01 {
    private int id;
    // Getters and Setters
}

public class TestResponseData02 {
    private String message;
    // Getters and Setters
}

one resource that returns a response of type TestResponse<TestResponseData01> and the other TestResponse<TestResponseData02>
In the test class, I have created a method that runs common tests of the responses of all resources, but I would like to return the TestResponse instance so that I can then run specific tests based on the resource I am testing.
private <T> TestResponse<T> commonTest(Response response, Class<T> dataType) {
    TestResponse<T> testResponse = response.readEntity(new GenericType<TestResponse<T>>(){});
    // ...
}

The problem is that the statement TestResponse<T> testResponse = response.readEntity(new GenericType<TestResponse<T>>(){}) deserializes the response JSON but for the TestResponse.Data field it instantiates an object of type java.util.LinkedHashMap
How can I execute the readEntity method so that the TestResponse.Data field is correctly instantiated with TestResponseData01 or TestResponseData02?
Full code
pom.xml dependecies
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <lombok.version>1.18.30</lombok.version>
        <jersey.version>2.25.1</jersey.version>
        <junit.version>5.11.2</junit.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Jersey -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JUnit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Jersey Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

JerseyTest class
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import javax.ws.rs.core.GenericType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestInstance;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestInstance.Lifecycle;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;

@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class Test_GenericType extends JerseyTest {
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Getter
    @ToString
    public static class TestResponse<T> {
        private boolean result;
        private int status;
        private T data;
    }
    
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Getter
    @ToString
    public static class TestResponseData01 {
        private int id;
    }
    
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Getter
    @ToString
    public static class TestResponseData02 {
        private String message;
    }
    
    @Path("testData01")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public static class TestResponseData01Resource {
        @GET
        public Response test() {
            TestResponseData01 testResponseData01 = new TestResponseData01(1);
            TestResponse<TestResponseData01> testResponse = new TestResponse<TestResponseData01>(true, Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode(), testResponseData01);
            return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(testResponse).build();
        }
    }
    
    @Path("testData02")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public static class TestResponseData02Resource {
        @GET
        public Response test() {
            TestResponseData02 testResponseData02 = new TestResponseData02("a");
            TestResponse<TestResponseData02> testResponse = new TestResponse<TestResponseData02>(true, Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode(), testResponseData02);
            return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(testResponse).build();
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig(TestResponseData01Resource.class, TestResponseData02Resource.class);
    }
    
    @BeforeAll
    public void before() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
    }
    
    @AfterAll
    public void after() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
    }
    
    private <T> TestResponse<T> commonTest(Response response, Class<T> dataType) {
        TestResponse<T> testResponse = response.readEntity(new GenericType<TestResponse<T>>(){});
        assertTrue(testResponse.isResult());
        assertEquals(200, testResponse.getStatus());
        return testResponse;
    }
    
    @Test
    void Test_ResponseData01Resource() {
        Response response = target("testData01").request().get();
        TestResponse<TestResponseData01> testResponse = commonTest(response, TestResponseData01.class);
        TestResponseData01 testData = testResponse.getData();
        assertEquals(1, testData.getId());
    }
    
    @Test
    void Test_ResponseData02Resource() {
        Response response = target("testData02").request().get();
        TestResponse<TestResponseData02> testResponse = commonTest(response, TestResponseData02.class);
        TestResponseData02 testData = testResponse.getData();
        assertEquals("a", testData.getMessage());
    }
}


First you need an utility class:
class MyParameterizedType implements ParameterizedType {

    private final Type rawType;
    private final Type[] params;

    private MyParameterizedType(Class clz, Class... params) {
        this.params = params;
        rawType = clz;
    }

    @Override
    public Type[] getActualTypeArguments() {
        return params;
    }

    @Override
    public Type getRawType() {
        return rawType;
    }

    @Override
    public Type getOwnerType() {
        return null;
    }
}

Then it is easy new GenericType(new MyParameterizedType(TestResponse.class, dataType)).

I added the two classes to my code and added the TestResponse<T> testResponse = (TestResponse<T>) response.readEntity(new GenericType(new MyParameterizedType(TestResponse.class, dataType))); statement but I get the error MyParameterizedType@770d0ea6 not a class or parameterized type whose raw type is a class

I deleted the MyType class and made these changes to the MyParameterizedType class: Class type (instead of MyType type) and types = Arrays.stream(params).toArray(Type[]::new) worked. I'll post the full code in the answer, thanks for the tip

@Charles Wow. I didn't notice that Class implements Type. Will fix my answer.
